# Python chdir works in IDLE but not in LiClipse

Tags: python

On IDLE 3.3.4 shell, I get satisfactory results :

```
>>> import os
>>> os.chdir('c:/cygwinroot')
>>> os.listdir()
['home']
>>>
```

But running the same code LiClipse leads to the error message that the name cygwinroot is not spelt correctly. What might be the problem ?

I am new to Python, but still this seems very intriguing.

Thanks for any help.

Manish Jain
invalid.pointer@gmail.com

Comment: try to use \\ instead of /. does it helps?

Comment: Already tried that. Does not work.

Comment: can you add your specific error message?

Comment: in addition, add the output of `os.path.abspath(os.curdir)` on both IDE. it is difficult to find the problem without this info

Comment: On IDLE, I get :>>> os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
'c:\\cygwinroot'

Comment: On IDLE, I get :>>> os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
'c:\\cygwinroot'. In LiClipse, the code is : import os
os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
os.chdir('c:/cygwinroot')
os.listdir()
os.path.abspath(os.curdir)

The strange thing when I run it (as pydev run), it just says "execution terminated". Now another interesting fact is, if I chdir not to c:/cygwinroot but somewhere under drive D: (where incidentally LiClipse is installed), it does not complain about bad directory name spelling. Although I still get "execution terminated" with no output.

Comment: I even tried changing LiClipse's interpreter from python3.3 to python3.4, but it does not help. Both interpreters are installed in the root of C: drive. Here is PATH env variable : C:\Python34\;C:\Python34\Scripts;C:\Python33\; plus other non-python stuff.